# Safari - iPhone simulator debugging (via "develop") not showing anymore

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios-simulator

I am using iPhone simulator to run a UIWebview, and Safari browser (on my mac) in order to debug the js / html / css code (via "develop" menu -> iPhone Simulator -> choosing my webview).

Yestarday, the iPhone-simulator option disappeared from my "develop" menu: (as you can see, the "iphone-simulator" is missing here (it is opened in the background and working...)

[image]

Any idea?

Edit: I am using iOS 7 iPhone simulator + Safari 7

Edit 2: Just tried opening a website on iphone-simulator's Safari browser (in addition to the UIWebview). No luck here as well...

Comment: Do you have the iOS Simulator launched?

Comment: What's running in your simulator? For it to appear the simulator needs to be running a website in either the `UIWebView` or mobile safari.

Comment: Hey - I am running a web page inside a UIWebview, on the simulator. It already worked for me for several days and suddenly stoped

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, what eventually worked for me was reseting the simulator (reset content and settings) and restarting my mac...

Comment: Is this broken for anyone who upgraded to ios 8.2?

Comment: After installing xcode-beta/Safari Technology Preview, I ran into the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 28):

I had exactly the same problem and I could not figure out how to solve it. Then I remembered that I actually have Safari Technology Preview installed on my Mac. And bang. The simulator device is visible in the Develop menu of the Technology Preview version.

Comment: Oh dear, same for me. I hope more lost souls will find this answer!

Comment: Thank you! (on behalf of lost souls everywhere)

Comment: This worked for me though I first followed all the other recommendations: Erase all content and settings on simulator, upgrade to latest OS (10.15.6) + update xCode to latest, restart computer then finally install Safari Tech Preview - and that's when I finally saw it.

Answer (score 23):

Sometimes it is necessary to restart Safari to make it notice new simulator, unfortunately.

i0S 11, Safari 11

Comment: Thank you, friend! Your advice really saves my day!

Answer (score 7):

in iOS 16.4 is mandatory to enable inspection to webView, to enable in Cordova apps, add the next code in **viewDidLoad**

```
#if DEBUG
    if let webView = webViewEngine?.engineWebView as? WKWebView {
        if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
            webView.isInspectable = true
        }
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. Solution was, closed Safari browser and Simulator and launched again. It fixed my problem. Restarting of my Mac was not required. Hope it will save someone's time.

Environment was as below:

1. MacBook Pro OSX version : 10.13.2
2. Safari browser version : 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3)
3. Simulator : iPhone 8 iOS version 11.2

Answer (score 2):

I restarted my simulator from Hardware->Restart and after that simulator option came in Safari Develop Menu.

Hope it will save someone's time.

Answer (score 2):

**Safari develop not showing**

You can run into this problem when your Safari's version does not support simulator's iOS version. As a result you can:

- Use `Safari Technology Preview`
- Use a lower iOS version on a simulator
- Restart iOS simulator when Safari is open(sometimes several times)

Answer (score 1):

With **iOS 16.4** comes a WebKit update which requires to enable the possibility to inspect the app for debugging WebView via Safari, **by default it's false.**

**Solution:**

```
_webView.inspectable = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes running your app on different iOS version helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all fixes and it did not fixed your problem. Then go for below steps
1. UnInstall Xcode

2. Install Xcode again
3. Restart you system
4. Download Command Line tool for Xcode (same version as xcode) 
   you can find command line tool https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ here
5. Install Command line tool

These steps fixed this problem for me, Hopefully it will fix someone's else as well. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the simulator or adding a new one.