# iOS Simulator with iOS 8 (Xcode 6) not showing up in Safari develop menu

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari

I'm using Xcode 6 and want to debug something in Safari mobile through the develop menu in Safari desktop. When I choose a device with iOS 7 the webpage shows up in the Safari desktop develop menu. When I choose device with iOS 8, no webpage shows up. Is this a bug or do I need to do something?

[image]

Comment: Try switching the debug setting off, then back on again in the Safari settings in Simulator, that worked for me. It looked like the preference wasn't storing correctly.

Comment: check your Safari version, update to the last

Comment: have you updated to Safari 7.1?

Comment: Updating Safari did the trick, if you answer the question I can accept it as the right answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safari - iPhone simulator debugging (via "develop") not showing anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277562/safari-iphone-simulator-debugging-via-develop-not-showing-anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS 8 Mobile Safari can only be inspected by Safari 8 on the Yosemite or the latest build of Safari (7.1) for Mavericks